# Redmine Install: Generate the session store

Tags: centos, redmine

I am stuck on this step.

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_install_Redmine_on_CentOS_5#Generate-the-session-store

Where do I write these lines. I tried in the terminal but nothing.

Any help?

Kind regards,

Khuram

Comment: @outis the answer was not available, hence question was left hanging.

Comment: @outis dude you're pushing too far. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about Ruby or Gems, but I know bundle is a shell script.  You should be able to find it in your path.  I installed Redmine on a server that already had Ruby configured, and found bundle here:

```
# which bundle
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin//bundle
```

Comment: Hi Joe, the complete line is
    RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake generate_session_store
which means that it is probably a variable assignment. I do not know where to write these lines. Do I just put the lines in putty starting from bundle part?